# Wordpress: Reducing Database Queries?

Tags: wordpress

First off, sorry if this is a basic question.

In wordpress, a lot of the template pages I build use `<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>` and `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>` to reference image files, scripts, links and downloads.

So my question is: would it be more efficient to declare a variable once in the header for all these links? e.g. `<?php $stylesheet = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>` then `<img src="<? $stylesheet ?>/images/something.jpg"/>`, instead of referencing the bloginfo query repeatedly on the page?

Thanks

*edited to make it clearer and give code examples

Comment: Are you referring to Wordpress itself, or a theme?

Comment: A theme, I have updated the question as the code had been stripped out of my original, hopefully makes more sense now!

Comment: It would be faster to simply hardcode the result of the query. For example, load the page and view the HTML source. Copy the HTML and paste it into header.php over the `bloginfo('template_url')` line. However, unless it is actually affecting your site's load time, I wouldn't do this because you need to remember to change it every time you change your theme.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) plugin.** It has everything you need:

- js and css in one file
- minification
- compression
- server caching
- CDN integration
- ...

plus it's easy to install and run.

You can also use [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/), but still W3's is the one I always use and no problems so far.

Comment: Thanks for that, that plugin looks interesting, I will give it a go on our staging server to see how it reacts with our slightly bodged wordpress installation!